# Passing parameter from PHP to javascript for date parameter

Tags: javascript, php, variables

here is the code I am using but does not seem to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

PHP code,

```
<?
$date = new DateTime($rdatetime);
        $sdate1 = $date->format('M d, Y H:I:s');
        echo $sdate1;
?>
```

Java Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Set the date we're counting down to
    //var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

    var countDownDate = new Date('$sdate').getTime();
    //var countDownDate = new Date("$sdate").getTime();
</Script>
```

I want to pass $sdate1 into $sdate. Hope I was able to explain my problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html hidden input to store data:

```
<input type="hidden" name="example" value="<?php echo $sdate1 ?>">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = document.getElementsByName("example")[0].value;
    //JQuery: 
    //var value = $('input[name=example]').val();
    var countDownDate = new Date(value).getTime();
</script>
```

Or using [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) or [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) attribute

```
<span id="date" data-date="<?php echo $sdate1 ?>"><?php echo $sdate1 ?></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = document.getElementById("searchTxt").getAttribute('data-date');
    //JQuery:
    //var value = $('input[name=example]').attr("data-date");
    //var value = $('input[name=example]').data("date");
    var countDownDate = new Date(value).getTime();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
$date = new DateTime($rdatetime);
        $sdate1 = $date->format('M d, Y H:I:s');
        echo $sdate1;
?> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Set the date we're counting down to
    //var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

    var countDownDate = new Date('<?=$sdate1;?>').getTime();
    //var countDownDate = new Date("$sdate").getTime();
</script>
```

Comment: Didn't see yours until after I submitted mine :) I forget with PHP you can do `<?=` now to echo variables.

Comment: What does `alert(<?=$sdate1;?>)` output?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is a little hacky, but this will do what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Set the date we're counting down to
    //var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

    var countDownDate = new Date('<?php echo $sdate ?>').getTime();
</Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean to do? Pass the php variable to js

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime($rdatetime);
    $sdate = $date->format('M d, Y H:I:s');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var countDownDate = new Date('<?php echo $sdate; ?>').getTime();
</script>
```